# How can we use GetRecordIds in a VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce

How can we convert following javascript button to Visualforce page.Especially "GETRECORDIDS",how can we write "GETRECORDIDS" logic in visualforce page.

I would like to convert following javascript button to visualforce page.

Please check the image i.e standard visualforce page. ***if the user checks the checkbox, I need that perticular "recordId" in controller.***

Here

- customobject__c.Id  is parent
  selected contains all "child records"
  checkbox has been checked

[image]

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")} 
  {!REQUIRESCRIPT ("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")} 
    var selected = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Opportunity)};
  if (selected[0] == null) { 
   alert("Please select at one custom object Record."); 
    } else{ 
  window.location.href='/apex/TestUpdateInquiry?
   id='+'{!customobject__c.Id}'+'&selected='+selected;
     }
```

Comment: Best you explain what you are trying to do so there is enough context to give an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to need a wrapper class to store your custom objects data. A wrapper class is a simple apex class, which stores a record, and adds additional information and methods.

Heres a basic example:

```
public class Controller {
    public List<WrapperClass> wrappers; 

    public Controller() {
        // Fill via query 
        wrappers = new List<WrapperClass>(); 
    }

    public List<Id> GetSelectedWrappers() {
        List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();

        for (WrapperClass wrapper:wrappers) {
            if (wrapper.selected) {
                ids.add(wrapper.record.Id);
            }
        }

        return ids; 
    }

    public class WrapperClass {
        public sObject record { get; set; }
        public Boolean selected { get; set; }

        public WrapperClass(sObject record) {
            this.record = record; 
            selected = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Inside your visualforce page, you'll need to expose a column for the user to interact with to select the wrappers.

```
<apex:repeat var="wrapper" value="{!wrappers}">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapper.Selected}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:outputField value="{!wrapper.Name}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:repeat>
```

Now you've got a class which contains your sObjects data, while providing an extra field (Selected) for use on the page. You can call `GetSelectedWrappers` to get the selected wrappers on the page, and then perform contextual actions based on your business needs.

For another example, you can read [this developer article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class), which has another good example of a wrapper class, and some extra info.